# How to add TrackingParticipant or change TrackingProfile after workflow was started?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

How can I add and remove a TrackingParticipant to a WorkflowServiceHost that is currently executing workflow instances, alternatively change the TrackingProfile of an already existing TrackingParticipant of that host?

The reason I need to do this is that the WorkflowServiceHost is executing workflows on certain events in our system, so it may run several workflows simultaneously. Now I need to enable tracing of these activities during runtime for diagnostic purposes upon a user request, an then disable them again when the user no longer needs them.  I can't restart the host because the workflows may be long running. However adding an extension to a WorkflowServiceHost that has already been associated with a workflow throws an exception. And the TrackingProfile of a TrackingParticipant seems to only be changeable at construction(?).

One way would be to simply have my TrackingParticipant have a boolean flag that indicated whether it was enabled or not, and then have it always track everything, but simply doing nothing with them if it was disabled. However, when I tried this the perfomance impact was not acceptable. Having a tracking participant that did absolutely nothing in its Track method made an example workflow consisting of a simple while-loop take 10 times longer to execute.

So is there any way to accomplish what I want here? And if not, why not?

Comment: 10 times longer with an empty `Track` method? That's odd, specially when tracking is asynchronous. Have you tried to override the [BeginTrack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.trackingparticipant.begintrack.aspx) instead? It's *default implementation is to call Track and return a Completed status.*

Comment: I see no other way than implement your custom tracking participant, just like you described it.

Comment: Overriding BeginTrack() is difficult to make more efficient I believe, since I'm not doing anything in the Track-method and I need to return an IAsyncResult and call the callback method and so on, so not sure how to do this in a more efficient way than what the base class does.

Any idea as to why this restriction is there, i.e. why one cannot change the filtering (TrackingProfile) of a participant during runtime?

Comment: Why do you said it cannot be changed at runtime? Is it throwing an exception when you set it? Decompile shows an auto-implemented property, without implementation. Now that I look [at it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.trackingparticipant.trackingprofile.aspx), it's virtual. Can't you override it and return the profile you want at *get* time?

Comment: Well, I can assign a different TrackingProfile to the TrackingParticipant at runtime, but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Have you tried to override TrackingParticipant's TrackingProfile property and do your logic on the get accessor? That's my last idea, otherwise WF is *caching* participant/profile somewhere at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, i tried that. It seems that the get-accessor on the TrackingProfile property is only called once during the workflow execution. :(

Comment: Well, I guess it answers part of your question. The runtime is caching the tracking participant along the way. My guess is that there isn't a supported way to do what you want.